# Internet Explorer freezes after submitting a file and getting a download

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

Using IE 11, I have this problem:
Within a html form I upload a file, and the PHP code just sends an download file back => The Internet Explorer now hangs.
It seems that this is just a new bug/behaviour, it worked without problems with IE just a week ago. I am using IE 11.0.9600.17207, Update 11.0.10 (KB 2962872). No problems with firefox or Chrome.

Here is the code to reproduce:
test5.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head>
<body>
<form action="test4.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input name="myfile" type="file"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="getUpdate" value="Get Update"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test4.php:

```
<?php
$update = "Ylpentuelps";
$filename = "test.text";
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($update));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-MD5: ".base64_encode(md5($update, true)));
print($update);
?>
```

If I access `http://<myserver>/test5.php`

and upload a file, I get immediately a download file to store in Chrome and Firefox, but with IE 11 the browser hangs.

Comment: It seems that the problem is related with the patch 2962872: 
* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2962872/en-us 
* http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/771e3435-1345-41cf-8682-d88abd5140a1/ie-10-and-11-freeze-after-kb2962872-web-application-with-file-uploaddownload?forum=ieitprocurrentver